# Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler in react JS

Tags: reactjs

I am using POP Up Modal form .Unable to change input value it goes into read only mode and showing Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler in react JS. Below I am sharing code. Please guide me where ia m doing wrong.

```
const handleInput = (e) => {
      setName(e.target.value)
   }

     <Modal show={showed}  size="lg" onHide={handleContactClose} aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg" centered scrollable  backdrop="static">
        
            <Modal.Header closeButton className='form-header'>
                <Modal.Title className='modal-heading contacts-model'>Add New Contact</Modal.Title>
             </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body className='contacts-form-body'>
          
             <Row className="mb-3">
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formPersonNgame" >
                    <Form.Label className='all-contacts-labels' >Person's Name</Form.Label>
                  
                    <Form.Control className='input-text-placeholders' name="name" type="text" placeholder="Person's Name" onChange={ (e) => {handleInput(e)}}  />
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formCompanyName">
                    <Form.Label className='all-contacts-labels'>Company Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className='input-text-placeholders' type="text" placeholder="Company Name" onChange={handleCompanyName}/>
                  </Form.Group>
             </Row>
     </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer className='form-header'>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleContactClose}>
                  Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" >
                  Save Changes
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
```

Comment: since its input you need to provide onChange property so when the input is changed you save the updated value

Comment: If you read OP's code they are providing the onChange handler, but they aren't binding the value to anything managed by react. You're going to want to use the useState() hook and from within your event handler call the changeState handler provided by useState to modify the value. You then should bind the value to the form control so that changes to that variable are reflected in the ui

Comment: I am unable to change value of input even I not able to write any thing in input box

Comment: I use use State hook but nothing happen

Comment: Because you're not binding the value to the form control. I'm going to submit an answer explaining shortly

Answer (score 0):

There is no value field in `Form.Control`.

```
<Form.Control className='input-text-placeholders' name="name" type="text" placeholder="Person's Name" value={name} onChange={ (e) => {handleInput(e)}}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you already are binding a handler to the form control,

```
function foo()=>{
let [myvalue,setmyvalue] = useState();

handler(e){
// do stuff and call setmyvalue
// this triggers a rerender
}

return(<input value={myvalue} onChange={handler}>)

}
```

you were correctly invoking your onChange handler, but weren't binding your value from useState to the form control